# Unpack data read from serial connection

Tags: python, struct

I read data from a serial connection line by line and get it in the following format:

```
b'002151BF,FFFF9F86'
b'002151C0,FFFF9F89'
b'002151C1,FFFF9F89'
b'002151C2,FFFF9F86'
b'002151C3,FFFF9F84'
b'002151C4,FFFF9F83'
b'002151C5,FFFF9F81'
b'002151C6,FFFF9F7E'
b'002151C7,FFFF9F79'
b'002151C8,FFFF9F76'
b'002151C9,FFFF9F70'
b'002151CA,FFFF9F69'
b'002151CB,FFFF9F67'
b'002151CC,FFFF9F66'
b'002151CD,FFFF9F66'
b'002151CE,FFFF9F68'
```

As you can see it's two 8 byte hex numbers divided by a comma.

How can I unpack this to decimal numbers? I've looked at struct.unpack, but can't figure out how to do it.

Your help will be highly appreciated - thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
3>> [int(x, 16) for x in b'002151BF,FFFF9F86'.split(b',')]
[2183615, 4294942598]

3>> [(int(x, 16) + 0x80000000) % 0x100000000 - 0x80000000 for x in b'002151BF,FFFF9F86'.split(b',')]
[2183615, -24698]
```

Comment: Ignacio - thx for your contribution - it looks very promising. Can you explain what's going on in the second version (where the result looks as expected)?

Comment: It just rolls the value over via offsetting, modulus, and removing the offset.

Comment: Please bear with my ignorance, but how could you see that the value should be 'rolled over'?

Comment: @user2739064: That many "F"s at the beginning of a hexadecimal number is a *good* indicator that the value should be negative.